# foreach loop not giving required result

Tags: php, curl

I'm performing an API request using PHP's cURL library. The output is XML as follows:

```
<xml>
   <urlnext>
    <list>
      <list1>
      <list2>
      <list3>
```

After getting this output, I'm calling the URL inside `urlnext` again with cURL and get a similar output and so on, if I keep on getting the `urlnext` in response we call the new URL with cURL library.

But that loop is calling the first response `urlnext` but not the next ones. It's giving response for first `urlnext` but it doesn't go for next loop. Please tell me how can I modify this loop. Here's my code:

```
$dat1 = httpGet($url);
$xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement($dat1);

foreach ($xml2 as $array) {
    $url  = $array->urlnext;
    $data = httpGet($url);
    $xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

    foreach ($xml2 as $array) {
        doing the operations.....
    }
}
```

The `httpGet` function is performing the cURL request and returning the XML as expected.

```
<?php

function getData($url){
   // $dat1=httpGet($url);
$ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'header1: value1',
    'header1:value2'
    )); 
    $output=curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
   //return $output;

    return new SimpleXMLElement($output);
}

//Create main array that will contain the XML responses of all the urls.
$mainData = Array();

//Pass in URL, calls getData function, finds next url, then calls its self with the new URL.  Be forewarned--- this could create an infinite loop
function loopData($url){
    $data = getData($url);
    array_push($mainData, $data);

    foreach($data as $array){
        $nexturl=$array->urlnext;
        loopData($nexturl);
    }
}
//Call initial URL
$url = "http://exampleurl.com";
loopData($url);

//Print all data results.
print_r($mainData);
?>
```

Comment: Use a diff variable name you are resetting $xml2 inside $xml2

Comment: even i do that.still doesnot work

Comment: your still getting only one iteration use a diff $array as well just for identification

Comment: sir.if i change the names at both places tht doesnt make a difference.as iteration is happening only once.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that jumps out right away to me is the missing "$" before the "data" variable on line 6.  But the shared variable names is concerning as well.

I'm not able to test this without knowing the API you're calling, but here was my initial stab at creating a piece of code that does what you described:

```
//Pass in URL to call, returns the XML element  
function getData($url){
    $dat1=httpGet($url);
    return new SimpleXMLElement($dat1);
}

//Create main array that will contain the XML responses of all the urls.
$mainData = Array();

//Pass in URL, calls getData function, finds next url, then calls its self with the new URL.  Be forewarned--- this could create an infinite loop
function loopData($url){
    $data = getData($url);
    array_push($mainData, $data);
    foreach($data as $array){
        $nexturl=$array->urlnext;
        loopData($nexturl);
    }
}
//Call initial URL
$url = "http://www.exampleurl.com";
loopData($url);

//Print all data results.
print_r($mainData);
```

Comment: I m getting a blank output.please check the code which i edited